# Paginate component fetches all data not paged data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a model and i want to paginate its data. all i do is, creating a model, something like this,

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {}
```

and include Paginator component in my controller and use it, something like this,

```
class MyControllers extends AppController
{
public $components = array('Paginator');

public function index()
{
$this->paginate['MyModel'] = array('limit'=>5);
print_r($this->paginate('MyModel'));
}
}
```

And I have a table with `my_controllers` name and it has 10 records. if everything was fine, the paginator component must give me 5 records for page one and 5 records for page 2. but it gives me 10 records without any paging.

What is the problem? :(

Thank you

Comment: I don't see a problem in this code (haven't tested it though). However, this is probably *not* your *actual* code, I really advise you to add the relevant parts of your *actual* code as well, as the problem may be somewhere in that code. You can add it to your question by clicking the [edit] link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Controller:

```
public function index() {
  $this->paginate = array('limit'=>5);
  $this->set('yourVariableNameHere', $this->paginate());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you so much. Thank you sir. You solved my problem. Thank you. I don't know why `$paginate` property does not work! if I set `$property` on the fly as you said the pagination will works fine. Why?